# Immediate Delivery of Notifications Using the new send() function in firebase cloud messaging?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an Android voice calling app and currently, I'm using the following Node.js server code to send incoming call notifications to the user's device:

```
var payload = {
  data,
};

var options = {
  priority: "high",
  timeToLive: 0,
  ttl: 0,
  android: {
    priority: "high",
    timeToLive: 0,
    ttl: 0,
  },
};

admin
  .messaging()
  .sendToDevice(deviceFcmId, payload, options)
  .then(function (response) {})
  .catch(function (response) {
    console.error("error sendNotification");
  });
```

The code is working correctly. However, I've come across documentation that suggests that `sendToDevice` is deprecated and advises to use the `send()` function instead. Unfortunately, the new documentation doesn't mention anything about `timeToLive` and message `priority`.

My question is, how can I ensure that my notification is sent immediately without any delay using the new send() function? Since this is an incoming call notification for the user, it should be delivered within a few seconds.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const message = {
  token: deviceFcmId,
  data: data,
  android: {
    priority: 'high',
    ttl: 0
  },
  apns: {
    headers: {
      'apns-priority': '10'
    }
  }
};

admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. But the ```ttl``` must be a ```Number```.